# Eclipse not compiling changes in any projects

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Eclipse has just stopped compiling changes to any of my projects, not sure why. I still have build automatically selected. Seeing as it affects all my projects I doubt that is the issue.

Comment: What symptom are you seeing that leads to this conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends.

Imported project from SVN/GIT? - Make sure the classpath and buildpath configurations are correct

Make sure your projects are Java projects

Make sure that your Source folders are on build path

Try restarting Eclipse or your machine from time to time

Prefs -> Java Compiler -> Use default compliance settings

Answer (score 1):

Starting Eclipse with the `-clean` parameter might also help if everything GGrec wrote doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Check this, if you have multiple projects in your Project Explorer that depend on each other:

Make sure there are no build path errors in one of your projects. You can find them in the Markers view (Window -> Show View -> Markers). Your project will have a red exclamation mark in the Project Explorer view as well.